# Find My Friends and Podcasts Bug in OS X iTunes

Tags: itunes, software-update, bug

Both Find My Friends and Podcasts apps are listed among the updates in iTunes on OS X, but when I attempt to update my apps there, I get a warning for each app:

[image]

This happens each time I update my apps in iTunes, and requires me to dismiss the dialog for each Find My Friends and Podcasts each time I do so.

If I can't update these two apps from iTunes, why are they listed there among my updates? And why are they listed there at all, given that they are not listed as needing an update on my phone?

How do I tell iTunes that these apps are already updated on my phone so that I don't see them listed among my updates any more?

Comment: Me too... though I've no clue why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete them from iTunes, but keep them on your phone. They're built into iOS 9 anyways so having them in iTunes is pointless

Comment: I'll give that a try.